# Building a mutli-user app in Ember.js

Tags: authentication, ember.js, sails.js

Forgive me if this is a poorly phrased or overly basic question.  I am an experienced device programmer, but very new to the world of web apps.

I have created a small emberjs app that lets the user create events, apply tags to them, and set a few basic properties for each.  I am using Sails for the backend, basically just out of the box.

As it presently exists, the app has no concept of 'users'.  There is not authentication, and everybody who goes to the server see all the events, tags, etc in the store.

My next step is to create a concept of users, associate certain events and tags with certain users and only allow authenticated users access to their own data in the store.

I am looking for a best practices or cookbook example of best practices for setting up my app to do this.  I have found several emberjs plugins that allow authentication, but that only solves part of the problem.

Comment: This is a bit of a broad question for StackOverflow.  Feel free to peruse / post in the [Sails.js Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!forum/sailsjs), browse the [documentation for the upcoming release](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM), and come back to SO when you have a specific implementation question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is somewhat generic, so this answer will be somewhat generic, but hopefully helpful.

The concept of having users who log in to your app immediately introduces the following requirements:

- You must have a data model for users
- Your backend must support **authentication** (so that we know John Doe really is John Doe), and EmberJS must be configured to work with this
- Your backend must support **authorization** (so that we know John Doe is authorized to access a certain event, and EmberJS must be configured to work with this.

Personally, I have not seen an "Ember Cookbook", but here are some tips:

**General Tips:**

- I find that making your frontend (Ember) and your backend (in your case, Sails) completely independent is the way to go.  This way, your app can easily support other frontends in the future like different Javascript frameworks, an iOS app, an Android app, etc.
- This means that you should FIRST decide how your API (backend) will handle authentication and authorization, and THEN figure out how to configure Ember to work with your API.  In practice, it's helpful to see what EmberJS libraries exist and then build your backend around them.

**Authentication:**

- For example, [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) is one popular library for handling authentication in Ember.  This library can be configured to authenticate using an OAuth 2.0 style (probably a good idea), or some other common authentication paradigms on the backend.
- With ember-simple-auth, the idea is that you authenticate your user (e.g. with username and password) and get a "token" in response.  By default, ember-simple-auth will then store the token in your brower's `localStorage` so that you user continues to be authenticated.
- You can further use out-of-the-box functionality here to handle redirecting to the login page if the user accesses a protected page without a valid sessions, etc.

**Authorization:**

- For authorization, this should be handled mostly on your backend.  ember-simple-auth will basically submit JSON requests to your backend. This will need to include the user's authentication token somewhere.  Ideally, it would be an HTTP Header, but it could be a JSON property.
- Either way, your API will then need to say "user `johnDoe` is requesting access to `event` #39. should I allow this?"  If yes, then your backend returns the resource, presumably as a JSON response.  If no, then your backend should still return a JSON response, but that JSON response should be a standard format for an error so your Ember app can say "Oh, I got this error JSON instead, and you can now display the details of the error (e.g. "Not authorized") to the end user.

**Summary:**

There are of course other ways to do things, but the "Ember Way" -- or more precisely, the "Ember Data Way" -- seems to be that Ember is your pure frontend and simply submits requests and responses to your JSON-based RESTful API, and then uses standard libraries to handle common patterns like authentication, session, redirect, error handling, etc.

Hope that helps.